# Getting blocked by CORS policy despite using a Filter

Tags: spring-boot, cors, http-headers

I have this `SimpleCORSFilter`:

```java
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PATCH,POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Everything works fine exceptn this one endpoint where I create my own `ResponseEntity` object in order to return paged content:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = ROOT + "/{businessId}/reviews", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<PagedResources<MenuReviewDto>> getAll(
        @PathVariable(name = "businessId") Long businessId,
        @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
        @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "10") Integer size,
        Sort sort,
        PagedResourcesAssembler assembler
) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, sort);
    Page<ReviewDto> reviews = this.reviewService.getAll(businessId, pageable);
    PagedResources<ReviewDto> pagedResources = assembler.toResource(reviews);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(pagedResources, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It's the only request that currently fails giving me the typical error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://192.168.1.144:8443/r/api/v1/admin/businesses/3/reviews?page=0&sort=createdAt,desc&size=5' from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The weird thing:

When debugging during this request, I can see that `doFilter()` of my `SimpleCORSFilter` is getting called. So the headers should be added?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was fast. And I post this here because it blows my mind a little.

I found this in the log output:

```
2019-08-1...ExceptionResolver : Resolved [org...Exception: Could not write JSON: ..
```

yadda, yadda, yadda ..

```
.. java.util.ArrayList[0]->mahlzeit.shared.review.ReviewRatingDto["isCut"])]
```

Now, let's see what `isCut` is:

```java
public class ReviewRatingDto {
    private Boolean isCut;

    // ..

    public void setIsCut(boolean isCut) {
        this.isCut = isCut;
    }

    public boolean getIsCut() {
        return isCut;
    }
}
```

The issue: It's the getter which returns `boolean` instead of `Boolean`. This was of course lazyily auto-generated code using my IDE of choice and ultimateively my own mistake but be aware that the resulting error might lead you to question your CORS settings ..